# Serializing List in Java to send as JSON

Tags: java, jquery, json, serialization

I am trying to serlialize my array in order for it to work even if it contains one element, this is what I did:

```
@GET
@XmlElement(name = "contentbean")
@Path("/retrieveContent")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JSONObject retrieve(@QueryParam("username") String Username, @QueryParam("path") String Path) throws JSONException {
    ContentBean oContentBean = buildResult(Username, Path);
    List<ContentBean> lContentBeans = new ArrayList<ContentBean>();
    lContentBeans.add(oContentBean);


    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.append("lContentBeans", lContentBeans);

    return jsonObject;
}
```

But on the client side I receive the following:

```
["[org.qcri.crosscloud.utils.ContentBean@7f29b922]"]
```

Which is basically an array of my Objects but every object becomes a string in the result. I need to get this:

```
{"ContentBean":[{"prop1":"val", "prop2":"val"}, {"prop1":"val", "prop2":"val"} ]}
```

Any idea?

Thanks,

**UPDATE 1**

Adopted J.Lucky's answer but now getting Exception as follows:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.qcri.crosscloud.utils.ACLBean and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.qcri.crosscloud.utils.ContentBean["acl"])
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here is my ContentBean

```
public static ContentBean buildResult(String sUsername, String sPath){

        //Scenario of retrieving an element that is a Directory (so no ACL)
        AttributesBean aB = new AttributesBean();
        aB.setName("profile/"); //From request
        aB.setType(false);  //Hard coded for testing purposes
        aB.setSize(0.2);   //Hard coded for testing purposes
        aB.setLastModified(new Date());

        ACLBean aclB = new ACLBean();
        RDFBean rdfB = new RDFBean();

        ContentBean cB = new ContentBean();
        cB.setUsername(sUsername); //From request
        cB.setAttributes(aB);
        cB.setACL(aclB);
        cB.setRDF(rdfB);

        return cB;
    }
```

ContentBean class:

```
@XmlRootElement 
public class ContentBean {

    private String username;
    private AttributesBean attributes;
    private RDFBean rdf;
    private ACLBean acl;

    /**
     * @return the attributes
     */
    public AttributesBean getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }

    /**
     * @param attributes the attributes to set
     */
    public void setAttributes(AttributesBean attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }

    /**
     * @return the rdf
     */
    public RDFBean getRDF() {
        return rdf;
    }

    /**
     * @param rdf the rdf to set
     */
    public void setRDF(RDFBean rdf) {
        this.rdf = rdf;
    }

    /**
     * @return the acl
     */
    public ACLBean getACL() {
        return acl;
    }

    /**
     * @param acl the acl to set
     */
    public void setACL(ACLBean acl) {
        this.acl = acl;
    }

    /**
     * @return the username
     */
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    /**
     * @param username the username to set
     */
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

}
```

**UPDATE 3**

Here is the client side:

```
function loadContent(sUsername, sPath)
        {
            arrayContentBeans = new Array();
            var sUrl = "http://localhost:8080/crosscloudservice/services/RDF/retrieveContent?username="+sUsername+"&path="+sPath;
            $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: sUrl,
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function parse(resp, status, xhr) {
                       $("#message").html("STATUS: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText + "\n" + resp);
                       $("#message").hide();
                       $.each(resp, function() {
                            $.each(this, function(i, cb) {
                                arrayContentBeans.push(cb);
                            });
                       });

                       renderContent();
                    },
                    error: function(resp, status, xhr){
                        $("#message").html("ERROR: " + resp.status + " " + resp.statusText + "\n" + xhr);
                        $("#message").show();
                    }

                });

        }
```

**UPDATE 4**

```
[ {
  "username" : "mzereba",
  "attributes" : {
    "name" : "profile/",
    "size" : 0.2,
    "type" : false,
    "lastModified" : 1410947312123
  },
  "rdf" : {
    "text" : null
  },
  "acl" : {
  }
} ]
```

Comment: Is that really what you need? Not what the list contains?

Comment: My list contains objects and I need them as JSON is what I need. Now for some reason is converting the object in a String.

Comment: If you need the content of the list, then the output will not look like that. It would look something like `{"ContentBean":[{"prop1":"val", "prop2":"val"}, {"prop1":"val", "prop2":"val"}
]}`

Comment: Exactly, that's what I'm trying to explain, why does it look like that? Sorry for my wrong explanation when I said "it should be like this. I'll correct that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)

```
ContentBean oContentBean = buildResult(Username, Path);
List<ContentBean> lContentBeans = new ArrayList<ContentBean>();
lContentBeans.add(oContentBean);

ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper()
            .configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false)
            .writer()
            .withDefaultPrettyPrinter();

String result = "";
try {
    result = ow.writeValueAsString(lContentBeans);
} catch(IOException ioe) {
    //do something
}
return result;
```

This will return a `String` so change your method declaration accordingly.

Here's the [download link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjacksonall190jar.htm) for the jar.

**EDIT 2:**
Since your `List` only contains one element, you can directly serialize it if you want so that you won't have to create a `List` anymore:

```
ContentBean oContentBean = buildResult(Username, Path);

ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper()
            .configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false)
            .writer()
            .withDefaultPrettyPrinter();

String result = "";
try {
    result = ow.writeValueAsString(oContentBean);
} catch(IOException ioe) {
    //do something
}
return result;
```

Comment: Thanks, but where can I download the Jackson jar? I went to download obviously but it takes me to git hub where I can only download the zip containing that read me explanation.

Comment: IS throwing an exception for the serialization for me now. I'll add it to my answer as update 1

Comment: not really, in fact I did surround it but gives me an empty result since the result string is initialized as empty. So it doesn't fill it up.

Comment: It is complaining about ACLBean that is part of the ContentBean, and it can be null. it talks about disabling something, could that be for null values?

Comment: I did post it, but I need to try to disable the fail on empty value he's telling me about. Where can I find that?

Comment: Thanks, it can't find "SerializationConfig", is it included in the Jackson jar?

Comment: Ok so it runs now, but it behaves exactly the same as without serialization :( I posted how I am looping it on the client side (check UPDATE 3), it should be fine.

Comment: I Added the print. But I tried multiple things earlier and as long as the JSON object (which is contained in curly bracket) is contained inside a square bracket as a hole container, it doesn't read it as an array what so ever. it has to be curly contained in curly. So basically as long everything contained in a square bracket, it doesn't work.

Comment: Am I doing an extra loop?

Comment: So I answer myself, Yes I am looping too much! I should simply take the "this" and save as the current element instead of looping it as well, and everything works fine :)